# Página llamada con window.open no carga los archivos .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Lo que quiero hacer:

- Llamar a una ventana que me muestre ciertos registros.

¿Cómo lo hago?

```
function cargarPaginaConsulta(par_pagina) {
    window.open(par_pagina, "child", "width=600,height=600");
}
```

En la página que llamo cargo, jQuery, Bootstrap y dos archivos .js

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:8080/susi/assets/img/susi-ico.ico">

<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://localhost:8080/susi/../terceros/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://localhost:8080/susi/../terceros/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://localhost:8080/susi/../comun/css/basico.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet"    href="http://localhost:8080/susi/assets/css/sistema.css"> 

<script src="http://localhost:8080/susi/../terceros/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/susi/../terceros/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://localhost:8080/susi/../comun/js/basico.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/susi/../comun/js/consulta.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

- El problema es que esta ventana no me está cargando los archivos .js
- Pero si pulso F5 ósea recargo la página si los carga.
- Utilizando el depurador de chrome puedo ver los archivos fuentes.

[image: Depurador de Chrome con los fuentes que está cargando]

Comment: ¿Dónde está la página dentro de tu estructura del sitio?

Comment: No puedo poner comentarios así que pregunto de esta forma: ¿Eso es el source pero que dice la consola? ¿Algún fichero da error?

Answer (score 1):

No comprendo exactamente qué necesidad hay de hacer eso, sin embargo aquí tienes una posible solución:

`window.open` te devuelve una instancia de la nueva ventana que has abierto, por lo tanto puedes manipular el DOM de tu nueva ventana a tu antojo, en tu caso, inyectar las librerías que necesitas aprovechando el objeto `document` de dicha instancia.

Crea un documento `html`, pega el siguiente ejemplo y ejecútalo en un navegador:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Open window</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="b">Go!</button>
  <script>

    var button = document.getElementById('b');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var anotherWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
      var libs = {
        jQuery:     'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js',
        underscore: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'
      };

      for (var name in libs) {
        if (libs.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          var script = anotherWindow.document.createElement('script');
          script.setAttribute('src', libs[name]);
          anotherWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
      }
   });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```